# logon failure when Refreshing the report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I had a application with Ms Acess database .In one of its form I use a Crystal report viewer to show a crystal report but the issue is that after loading its giving blank report and if I try to refresh the  report its giving the error [image]

My code is as below

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = getpeport(@"C:\shrinkage\New folder\Shrinkage details1-bysreenath.rpt");



                crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{CONS_MAST.CONSID} = '" + cmb_cons.Text + "' and {CONSUMPTION.STYLE} = '" + cmb_style.Text + "' and {CONSUMPTION.BUYER} = '" + cmb_buyer.Text + "'";
            //crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport ();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                oleDbConnection1.Close();
            }
          //  crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }        



        public ReportDocument getpeport(String ReportLocation)
        {
            ConnectionInfo crconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            ReportDocument cryrpt = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crtablelogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtablelogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

            Tables CrTables;



            crconnectioninfo.ServerName = @"C:\shrinkage\Shrinkage.mdb";
            crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "";
      crconnectioninfo.UserID = "";
     crconnectioninfo.Password = "";

            cryrpt.Load(ReportLocation);

            CrTables = cryrpt.Database.Tables;

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtablelogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crconnectioninfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo);
            }
          //  cryrpt.Refresh ();
            return cryrpt;
        }
```

This report was designed in Crystal report XI and there I am able to do the refresh and view the data also.Pls help me with a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "oleDBConnection1.Open();" to the beginning of your button1_Click method. You close the connection at the end, but you never open it.